# Custom UiSlider IOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider, ios6

So i have this piece of code that creates a custom UISlider . It works fine until IOS 6. In IOS 6 the images are not displayed and it shows the default slider . Can somebody please explain why this happens ?

```
[sliderFPS setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_slider_empty.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8 topCapHeight:0]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sliderFPS setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_slider_full.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8 topCapHeight:0]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[sliderFPS setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_fps_slider_button"]      
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help..

Because below methos is deprecated in iOS 5.

```
 - (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

According to your code, use this one instead of first two line.

```
[sliderFPS setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_slider_empty.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(@"8")]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sliderFPS setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_slider_full.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsFromString(@"8")]
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` was deprecated in iOS 5 use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` instead

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean it's not available or usable. It means it was replaced by a newer method, to which you SHOULD transition (but not required to) as it will in the near future not be available anymore. Is it completely removed in iOS 6?

Comment: it should (it returns an image for me) still work in iOS6, but shouldn't be relied on and given this was a change in iOS6 maybe the behaviour isnt always the same

Comment: Yes, you should change the code before submitting a new build, but I don't believe that this is the reason why the slider isn't working anymore....

Comment: very possible thats not the reason, it's just the only possible thing I can see from this code

Comment: that was the issue. Thanks . I accepted Bapu response since he was the first to post it .